# how do i fix this Azure event hub AMQP error?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to post to Azure event hub with the basic template code from the Microsoft Docs.

I have tried connecting via connection string as well and I have tried to look in the docs but I can't find someone else with this issue.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer;
using System.Text;

// number of events to be sent to the event hub
int numOfEvents = 3;

// The Event Hubs client types are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime
// of the application, which is best practice when events are being published or read regularly.
// TODO: Replace the <EVENT_HUB_NAMESPACE> and <HUB_NAME> placeholder values
EventHubProducerClient producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(
    "<EVENT_HUB_NAMESPACE>.servicebus.windows.net",
    "<HUB_NAME>",
    new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Create a batch of events 
using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

for (int i = 1; i <= numOfEvents; i++)
{
    if (!eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Event {i}"))))
    {
        // if it is too large for the batch
        throw new Exception($"Event {i} is too large for the batch and cannot be sent.");
    }
}

try
{
    // Use the producer client to send the batch of events to the event hub
    await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
    Console.WriteLine($"A batch of {numOfEvents} events has been published.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
finally
{
    await producerClient.DisposeAsync();
}
```

But i keep getting this error message.

```
    Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: null TrackingId:7c3236fa44f547a5b39a4478722e674b_G10S1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2024-01-25T08:30:42

 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpException: null TrackingId:7c3236fa44f547a5b39a4478722e674b_G10S1, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2024-01-25T08:30:42

   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.OpenAmqpObjectAsync(AmqpObject target, Nullable`1 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: AMQP errors in Azure Event [Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-amqp-troubleshoot) and AMQP 1.0 in Azure Service Bus and Event Hubs protocol [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide)

Comment: Been there, can't find any help there.

Comment: for event [hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/transport-layer-security-configure-client-version?tabs=dotnet)  [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/transport-layer-security-configure-minimum-version)

Answer (score 1):

The error details indicate that this is an unusual failure on the Event Hubs service, not something that the client has insight nor influence over.  Your best path forward will be to [open an Azure support request](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), as you'll need service assistance.  The tracking id and timestamp in that message will allow them to reference the service logs for this specific incident.

The client throws an `InvalidOperationException` in only one scenario - the service responded with an AMQP error code of "amqp:not-allowed".  *([src](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Amqp/AmqpError.cs#L252))*

This is annotated as meaning "the service does not understand how to process the request" - which is not something that we should see under normal circumstances when attempting to open a connection/link, which is what the stack trace indicates was happening.

That you're able to reproduce using the connection string and credential would seem to indicate that there may be a problem with the Event Hubs namespace resource itself.

Note that this does not indicate an auth failure - those would come back with AMQP code "amqp:unauthorized-access" and be translated into an `UnauthorizedAccessException` by the client.